Windows' gdisk usage in real correct way
How to run gdisk for and/or on Windows  under MSYS2/Mingw64,
as
$ gdisk

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sda
Problem opening /dev/sda for reading!  

Trying to put other many guessed storage device synonym names end up to no avail

Read the documentation first

Windows—Windows disk device references officially take the form \\.\physicaldrive#, where # is a number, as in \\.\physicaldrive0. Since this is awkward, gdisk supports a simpler specification of #:, as in 0: to refer to the first disk. Note that letters followed by a colon, as in C: or D:, refer to partitions, not whole disks; gdisk doesn't accept partition names as drive identifiers.
A gdisk Walkthrough by Rod Smith (Archive)

Also check Win32 Device Namespaces
